# Terminate a hung redis pubsub.listen() thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, redis, redis-py

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654243/recover-from-dropped-connection-in-redis-pub-sub) I have the following code which subscribes to a redis pubsub queue and uses the handler provided in __init__ to feed the messages to the class that processes them:

```
from threading import Thread
import msgpack

class Subscriber(Thread):

    def __init__(self, redis_connection, channel_name, handler):
        super(Subscriber, self).__init__(name="Receiver")
        self.connection = redis_connection
        self.pubsub = self.connection.pubsub()
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.handler = handler
        self.should_die = False

    def start(self):
        self.pubsub.subscribe(self.channel_name)
        super(Subscriber, self).start()

    def run(self):
        for msg in  self.pubsub.listen():
            if self.should_die:
                return
            try:
                data = msg["data"]
                unpacked = msgpack.unpackb(data)
            except TypeError:
                # stop non-msgpacked, invalid, messages breaking stuff
                # other validation happens in handler
                continue
            self.handler(unpacked)

    def die(self):
        self.should_die = True
```

In the linked question above, it is noted that `pubsub.listen()` never returns if the connection is dropped. Therefore, my `die()` function, while it can be called, will never actually cause the thread to terminate because it is hanging on the call to `listen()` inside the thread's `run()`.

The accepted answer on the linked question mentions hacking redis-py's connection pool. I really don't want to do this and have a forked version of redis-py (at least until the fix is hopefully accepted into master), but I've had a look at the redis-py code anyway and don't immediately see where this change would be made.

Does anyone have an idea how to cleanly solve the hanging redis-py `listen()` call?

What issues will I incur by directly using `Thread._Thread__stop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out after so many years. It ended up being a bug in the redis library. I debugged it and submitted the [PR](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/pull/465). It shouldn't occur any more.